# C++ friend got no this?

Tags: c++, class, methods, friend

I just though about this and found no answer in the web.
If a method isn't defined as static then it has a const pointer to a member of the class (**this**), But why this isn't true about friends?

For example the following won't compile:

```
class B {
private:
    int n;
public:
    B (int x) : n(x){}
    B operator+ (B &b)
    {
        return B(n+b.n);
    }
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, const B& b)
    {
        out << "B: " << this.n;//Bug is here
        return out;
    }
    bool operator <(const B & rhs)
    {
        return n<rhs.n;
    }
};
```

Comment: Friend functions are not member functions

Comment: Accept the answers if you feel it helped/answered your question

Comment: `this.n` should be `b.n`. the operator can access the private member `n`of `b` because of the `friend` declaration